# apply a css class conditionally if another class exists jquery/rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with checkboxes - if one of these is checked, there is some jquery that applies the css class `checkboxed`.

I have another `div` further down the page that is hidden by default - but if *any* of the form checkboxes are checked, it should become visible.

I'd like to use something like this

```
<div class="<%= "hide" unless checkboxed.exists? %>">
```

but obviously that doesn't work.  Is there a way to test if a css class exists on a given page?  I know I'll have to use jQuery, but how to then tie this in with the conditional CSS class in the hidden `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the div showing logic to the place where you react to checking a box.The addition might look like this:

```
if($('.checkboxed').length)
    $('#hiddenDiv').show();
```

Your hidden div must have an ID, here I assumed `id="hiddenDiv"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbox = $('checkbox').attr("checked");

if (checkbox == 'checked') {
    $('#divID').show(); // #divID is the ID for the hidden DIV which you want to show.
}
```